Cannot install any packages or using dpkg configure
I did an upgrade to my machine lubuntu 22.04 and it failed, Now i cannot upgrade or install anything.
user@host:~$ sudo apt remove cmatrix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cmatrix linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 14.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 352555 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Removing cmatrix (2.0-3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Cmatrix here is an example.
I tried sudo dpkg --configure -a and it showed me
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 depends on linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 (= 6.5.0.41.41~22.04.2); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04



also tried sudo apt install -f
result was :

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 14.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 352545 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic (6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)




I wish someone helps me with this issue.
Thanks.

Is /boot perhaps mounted read-only? Check with findmnt -T /boot

If the upgrade filed and BTW you never said upgrade from what to what There is a very good chance you will need to do a reinstall.

/boot  /dev/sda2 vfat   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,er

OK so the issue appears to be that your /boot is on a vfat filesystem - which doesn't support symbolic links. If this is an EFI system then I believe it's OK for /boot/efi to be vfat, but /boot itself should be on the / filesystem. I'm not sure the best way to resolve that - let's see if anyone else has ideas.

i mounted /boot on seperated partition, should i unmount it then?

disable symlinks etc/kernel-img.conf
do_symlinks = no
no_symlinks = yes


This is not a fix and will mess up the system in many others ways if the OP is able to fix without a reinstall.
